# Is "华彧" an acceptable name for males? Any other boy names with "华"?

Tags: names, culture

I have been learning Chinese for several months now, and I would love to have a Chinese name to facilitate conversing and learning, mainly for my own enjoyment.

I feel that whatever my name will be, it should include "华" since that character means so much to me.

To find the other part, I narrowed down my list to "彧" for aesthetic reasons, and it has nice meanings. But because I am not yet familiar with Chinese culture and history, could anyone tell me if I could use this name or not?

And if possible, could you guys suggest some of your favorite characters that could go well with "华"? Thank you so much and I wish you all health and happiness in life!

EIDT: I just did some more google search and found that my last name in Chinese is 黎.

Answer (score 1):

The most famous person with 彧 in his name was 'Xun Yu ([荀彧](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xun_Yu))' in the Three Kingdoms period, so 彧 was a legit name, but it is rarely used in modern time.

If you do decide to name yourself 华彧, people will inevitably associate your name with 荀彧 and get the impression that you are proclaiming yourself a wise and capable advisor ... Are you one?

Zhuge Liang (諸葛亮) was the more famous advisor than 荀彧 in the Three Kingdoms period, but the character 亮 is a common character, so no one would associate it with 諸葛亮 specifically, but the character 彧 is so rare, everyone who read the novel Romance of Three Kingdoms would think of him immediately upon seeing 彧 in a name

> 彧 《广韵》有文章也,《广雅》文也

> 彧 means "literary talent" or "literary"

If you want a common character that has a similar meaning to 彧, 文 should be the best choice, but 华文 would mean "Chinese text" or "Chinese language"

黎文华 would be a decent name. Both 文 and 华 are popular characters in names

If you want a common character that sounds like 彧 /yù/ and goes well with 华, you can consider 黎华禹，黎华鈺，黎华裕

Comment: Thank you for your help. As for the impression, I would like to be that. But since "彧" is rarely used nowadays, could you suggest your favorite character(s) that could go with "华"? My last name in Chinese is "黎" if you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

彧 is rarely used. In fact I think many people who aren't familiar with Three Kingdoms would have no idea how to pronounce this character.

As the other guy said, because of the rareness, people would tend to associate the character with famous people like 荀彧, which might or might not affect how they view/perceive you.

If you are ok with that then it's fine, name sounds decent.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand the possible pronunication issue now. Could you suggest your favorite character(s) that could go with "华" then? My last name in Chinese is "黎".